# Android Firebase phone Authentication: how to check the first login?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to make a default authorization.

When a user logs in to the application for the first time by phone number, I want some data (wordPacks, status, etc.) to set in my Realtime Database. And when the user logout and login again, I want the user to see his relevant data, not default one from the first login.

I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to correct it.

```kotlin
private fun singInWithCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        val mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(baseActivity) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    val firebaseUserId = task.result?.user!!.uid
                    val map = hashMapOf(
                        "id" to firebaseUserId,
                        "username" to "Superhero",
                        "imageURL" to "url",
                        "wordPacks" to userDictionaryPacks,
                        "status" to "online"
                    )
                    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUserId)
                    reference.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener { curTask ->
                        if (curTask.isSuccessful) {
                            if (isOnboardingViewed()) {
                                navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                            } else {
                                navigate(VerificationFragmentDirections.actionVerificationFragmentToOnboardingFragment())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    otpSmsCode.text?.clear()
                    Snackbar.make(root, "Incorrect verification code. Try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
```

Can you help me?

**UPDATE:**

This question is not duplicate.

The link contains a question to Firebase Facebook login.

Although both are related to Firebase Login, *this post* is actually logins with user **mobile number** while the link of the *other post* is about login with **facebook**.

The implementation of both are totally different and doesn't at all answer to this question. Please un-duplicate this question so it deserves to be answered.

Comment: What's the problem when you run this code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, After I looked at what you suggested, the problem disappeared. Thank you very much, I will carefully look at the documentation next time